# How to determine duplicate entries in sources.list

Tags: debian, package-management, repository

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` was growing over time and now contains 100 lines (including `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`). I clearly have duplicate entries, which apt doesn't recognise. To give an obvious, but fictitious example:

```
deb http://ftp.am.debian.org/debian buster main contrib
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian buster main contrib
```

I'd like to include all the reliable packages available for [Debian](https://www.debian.org) (ignoring [inofficial packages](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Unofficial), the mess in my `sources.list` would just increase with these…) while keeping my `sources.list` as short as possible.

I also don't want to start all over again (e. g. with an example `sources.list`) because I already put too much effort in. Sorting them out by hand (e. g. commenting out one-by-one and removing the entries without a change in the number of available packages) is really not favourable because of the amount of entries.

As a next step, including "semi-official" or [inofficial packages](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Unofficial) to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` would be favourable.

Needless to say, I'd like to choose a stable, officially listed mirror nearby including all packages for my pc's architecture.

If possible, I'd also like to have as little different domains as possible for increasing clarity in my `sources.list` files.

Comment: It may be a tool or some guideline with which I don't have to uncomment every entry, `apt[itude] update`, compare the number of available packages and then leave or remove the watched entry. There's also the confusion that `deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates main contrib` and `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib` give the feeling being the same… How to be sure I haven't included packages multiple times (from different mirrors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to weed out duplicates, without resorting to trial-and-error, is to look at the output of `apt policy`. For each accessible repository (and suite, and architecture), `apt policy` will show the repository descriptor; you should try to end up with only one of each.

For example, with the repositories you list in your question, `apt policy` will show something like

```
 500 http://ftp.am.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.am.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.au.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.am.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin ftp.am.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin ftp.au.debian.org
```

The second line of each entry is the one which needs to be de-duplicated; in the 
example above

```
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
```

and

```
     release v=10.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
```

The simplest option when choosing which entry to keep is to have one `deb.debian.org` entry (that will use a redirection to give you a close mirror every time).

Comment: It seems to have worked.